# C++ linked list input memory not carrying over (Maybe)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am quite inexperienced at coding so I am not sure what is going on, but I have run my code through godbolt compiler/debugger, and it says that there is a memory leak but I don't know how to solve this problem I do believe the issue is within the void end function though.

[GodBolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/eq1aGcTqP)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int value = 0;
    string month;
    node* next;
};

struct NewValues {
    long int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;
} n;

//function moves newvalues infront of linked list
void AtFront(node** head)
{
    node* Dec = new node();
    Dec->value = n.c;
    Dec->month = "December 2021: $";
    Dec->next = *head;
    *head = Dec;

    node* Nov = new node();
    Nov->value = n.b;
    Nov->month = "November 2021: $";
    Nov->next = *head;
    *head = Nov;

    node* Oct = new node();
    Oct->value = n.a;
    Oct->month = "October 2021: $";
    Oct->next = *head;
    *head = Oct;
}

//puts new values at the end of the linked list
void End(node** head)
{
    node* June = new node();
    June->value = n.d;
    June->month = "June 2022: $";
    June->next = NULL;

    //if linked list is empty, newnode will be a head node
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = June;
        return;
    }

    //find the last node
    node* last = *head;
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }

    last->next = June;

    node* July = new node();
    July->value = n.e;
    July->month = "July 2022: $";
    July->next = NULL;
    last->next = July;

    node* Aug = new node();
    Aug->value = n.f;
    Aug->month = "August 2022: $";
    Aug->next = NULL;
    last->next = Aug;
}

void sumOfNodes(node* head, long int* sum)
{
    // if head = NULL
    if (!head)
        return;

    // recursively traverse the remaining nodes
    sumOfNodes(head->next, sum);

    // accumulate sum
    *sum = *sum + head->value;
}

int sumOfNodesUtil(node* head)
{
    long int sum = 0;

    // find the sum of  nodes
    sumOfNodes(head, &sum);

    // required sum
    return sum;
}

void printList(node* n)
{
    cout << "\nList of earnings from October 2021 - August 2022\n" << endl;
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->month << n->value << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node* head = new node();
    node* second = new node();
    node* third = new node();
    node* fourth = new node();
    node* fifth = new node();

    cout << "There are a total of 6 months unaccounted for.." << endl;
    cout << "please enter in the data for the month when prompted" << endl;

    cout << "\nOctober 2021: $";
    cin >> n.a;

    cout << "November 2021: $";
    cin >> n.b;

    cout << "December 2021: $";
    cin >> n.c;

    cout << "June 2022: $";
    cin >> n.d;

    cout << "July 2022: $";
    cin >> n.e;

    cout << "August 2022: $";
    cin >> n.f;

    head->value = 500;
    head->month = "January 2022: $";
    head->next = second;

    second->value = 125;
    second->month = "Febuary 2022: $";
    second->next = third;

    third->value = 200;
    third->month = "March 2022: $";
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->value = 300;
    fourth->month = "April 2022: $";
    fourth->next = fifth;

    fifth->value = 600;
    fifth->month = "May 2022: $";
    fifth->next = NULL;

    AtFront(&head);
    End(&head);
    printList(head);

    long int avg = sumOfNodesUtil(head) / 11;

    cout << "\nTotal earnings: $" << sumOfNodesUtil(head) << endl;
    cout << "Average: $" << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: you've got lots of `new`s but not a single `delete` so memory leaks aren't surprising?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but can you explain further I am not sure what a delete or a new is that is resulting in a memory leak?

Comment: [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) creates objects, [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) destroys them

Comment: Add the `-g` option and the sanitizer reports become clearer. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ErhTEaKvW)

Comment: _"I am not sure what a delete or a new is"_ - how on earth did you manage to write this program without knowing that?

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't do garbage collection unless you explicitly ask for it and have a library that implements it. Everything you `new` you are responsible for `delete`ing after you're done using it (and no sooner--you'd be surprised how hard it can be to get this right).

Comment: Often the linked list assignment is used in programming courses to teach when and where `new` and `delete` must be used, along with the importance of book-keeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every use of `new` to dynamically allocate memory, you must also use `delete` to deallocate that memory. You have used `new` but not `delete` so you have a memory leak.

When dealing with a linked list, each node links to the next. The trick is that if you delete a node, you've deleted the pointer to the rest of the list, but not the data it points to.

Consider a very basic linked list. (The principle transfers.)

I'm going to give it a constructor for ease of use.

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;

    Node(int v, Node *n=nullptr) : val(v), next(n) { }
};
```

We can allocate a new node:

```
Node *head = new Node(42);
```

And a list with a few items:

```
Node *head = new Node(42);
head->next = new Node(27);
head->next->next = new Node(13);
```

Now, if I `delete head;` I haven't actually deleted the next two nodes. Rather I've destroyed anyway of getting to those to delete them, guaranteeing I'll leak memory.

We can iterate over the list and delete as we go, using temp pointers so we don't lose track of the rest of the list.

```
Node *head = new Node(42);
head->next = new Node(27);
head->next->next = new Node(13);

Node *temp = head;
while (temp) {
    Node * temp2 = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    temp = temp2;
}
```

We can integrate this functionality into a destructor.

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;

    Node(int v, Node *n=nullptr) : val(v), next(n) { }

    ~Node() {
        Node *temp = next;
        while (temp) {
            Node *temp2 = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = temp2;
        }
    }
};
```

With the destructor, the list will clean itself up automatically when going out of scope *if* it's been automically allocated; or *if* it's been dynamically allocated with `new`, we need only delete the head:

```
Node *head = new Node(42);
head->next = new Node(27);
head->next->next = new Node(13);

delete head;
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure on how to do so because what I have tried so far when deleting the pointers results in a lose of data, so would you show me how to resolve this issue as I believe it will help me understand better. Thank you, Chris!

Comment: @HW19 You should get familiar with RAII. Read about that at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) and also [The rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Reading those will shed some light on how to deal with resource management.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you very much for the advise I will definitely look into it to make myself a better programmer!

Answer (score 0):

*****My code :: FIXED*****

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip> //library needed for setprecision 

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int value = 0;
    string month;
    node* next;
};

struct NewValues {
    long int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0;
} n;

void front(node* *head)
{
    node* Dec = new node();
    node* Nov = new node();
    node* Oct = new node();
    
    Dec->value = n.c;
    Dec->month = "December 2021: $";
    Dec->next = *head;
    *head = Dec;

    Nov->value = n.b;
    Nov->month = "November 2021: $";
    Nov->next = Dec;
    *head = Nov;

    Oct->value = n.a;
    Oct->month = "October 2021: $";
    Oct->next = Nov;
    *head = Oct;
}

void end(node* *head)
{
    node* June = new node();
    node* July = new node();        
    node* Aug = new node();

    //if linked list is empty, newnode will be a head node
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = June;
            return;
        }
        
        //find the last node
            node* last = *head;
                while (last->next != NULL) {
                    last = last->next;
                }

    Aug->value = n.f;
    Aug->month = "August 2022: $";
    Aug->next = NULL;
    last->next = Aug;
    
    July->value = n.e;
    July->month = "July 2022: $";
    July->next = Aug;
    last->next = July;
    
    June->value = n.d;
    June->month = "June 2022: $";
    June->next = July;
    last->next = June;

}

void sumOfNodes(node* head, long double* sum)
{
    // if head = NULL
    if (!head)
        return;

    // recursively traverse the remaining nodes
    sumOfNodes(head->next, sum);

    // accumulate sum
    *sum = *sum + head->value;
}

int sumOfNodesUtil(node* head)
{
    long double sum = 0;

    // find the sum of  nodes
    sumOfNodes(head, &sum);

    // required sum
    return sum;
}

void printList(node* n)
{
    cout << "\nList of earnings from October 2021 - August 2022\n" << endl;
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->month << n->value << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(node* *head_ref)
{
  
    /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
    node* current = *head_ref;
    node* next = NULL;
  
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
  
    /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back
        in the caller. */
    *head_ref = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, This program takes in input for unaccounted months from your";
    cout << " salary over the months and prints them out, \nalong with the total and average." << endl;
    cout << "\nThere are a total There are 11 months and 6 months unaccounted for.." << endl;
    cout << "please enter in the data for the months when prompted" << endl;
    
    cout << "\n------------------------" << endl;
    
    cout << "October 2021: $";
    cin >> n.a;

    cout << "November 2021: $";
    cin >> n.b;

    cout << "December 2021: $";
    cin >> n.c;

    cout << "June 2022: $";
    cin >> n.d;

    cout << "July 2022: $";
    cin >> n.e;

    cout << "August 2022: $";
    cin >> n.f;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    
    node* head = new node();
    node* second = new node();
    node* third = new node();
    node* fourth = new node();
    node* fifth = new node();
    
    head->value = 500;
    head->month = "January 2022: $";
    head->next = second;

    second->value = 125;
    second->month = "Febuary 2022: $";
    second->next = third;

    third->value = 200;
    third->month = "March 2022: $";
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->value = 300;
    fourth->month = "April 2022: $";
    fourth->next = fifth;

    fifth->value = 600;
    fifth->month = "May 2022: $";
    fifth->next = NULL;

    front(&head);
    end(&head);
    printList(head);
    
    long double avg = sumOfNodesUtil(head) / 11;

    cout << "\n\n------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Total earnings: $" << setprecision(6) << sumOfNodesUtil(head) << endl;
    cout << "Average: $" << setprecision(6) << avg << endl;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\nDeleting Linked List..." << endl;
    
    deleteList(&head);
    
    cout << "\nLinked List Deleted\n\n\tProgram Terminated..." << endl;
}
```

I had realised I did not link the end function nodes together properly, but now I have fixed the issue and the code woks as intended